# are there downsides to hosting an .exe file on a linux server

Tags: content-filter

Client has decided to use a technology that has an "offline" version using an .exe file on a web server.

Is there any downside to hosting an .exe file, ie. may it get you blocked or rated/ marked in any way in search engines or common content filters?

More specifically, how would Google determine that your web site has spyware or a virus. How would an antivirus manufacturer determine if your website contains spyware or malware?

Comment: Um, by downloading it and running it through a virus scanner?

Comment: not sure this is really a SF question.  Maybe it would fit on webmasters?

Comment: NO downsides to hosting it... only attempting to use/execute it......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any downside to hosting an .exe file, ie. may it get you
>   blocked or rated/ marked in any way in search engines or common
>   content filters?

No.

By and large, HTTP clients do not know nor do they care what is on the other end of their HTTP requests, so long as the server delivers content as intended.

> More specifically, how would Google determine that your web site has
>   spyware or a virus. How would an antivirus manufacturer determine if
>   your website contains spyware or malware?

By downloading the assets on your website and testing them against their database of known virii and other heuristics.

Comment: just extended the question a bit

Comment: @jdog Answer edited to reflect your second question. What connection do your two questions have? Is your client hosting malware?

Comment: No, but if anyone in the world would have the smallest impression of them doing that, it would discourage the client using the technology in the first place.

Comment: If this is something your client is concerned about, either they are *really* paranoid, or they are actually doing something nefarious.